# Matlab: how to find an enclosing grid cell index for multiple points

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to allocate (x, y) points to the cells of a non-uniform rectangular grid. Simply speaking, I have a grid defined as a sorted non-equidistant array

```
xGrid = [x1, x2, x3, x4];
```

and an array of numbers `x` lying between `x1` and `x4`. For each `x`, I want to find its position in `xGrid`, i.e. such `i` that

```
xGrid(i) <= xi <= xGrid(i+1)
```

Is there a better (faster/simpler) way to do it than `arrayfun(@(x) find(xGrid <= x, 1, 'last'), x)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the second output of [`histc`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html):

```
[~,where] = histc(x, xGrid)
```

This returns the array `where` such that `xGrid(where(i)) <= x(i) < xGrid(where(i)+1)` holds.

### Example:

```
xGrid = [2,4,6,8,10];
x = [3,5,6,9,11];
[~,where] = histc(x, xGrid)
```

Yields the following output:

```
where =
     1     2     3     4     0
```

---

If you want `xGrid(where(i)) < x(i) <= xGrid(where(i)+1)`, you need to do some trickery of negating the values:

```
[~,where] = histc(-x,-flip(xGrid));
where(where~=0) = numel(xGrid)-where(where~=0)
```

This yields:

```
where =
     1     2     2     4     0
```

Because `x(3)==6` is now counted for the second interval `(4,6]` instead of `[6,8)` as before.

Comment: Excellent! I didn't hope to find *such* a simple solution. And for a grid of 10^5 points it's roughly 100 times faster than my method. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If `x` is a column this might help

```
xg1=meshgrid(xGrid,1:length(x));
xg2=ndgrid(x,1:length(xGrid));
[~,I]=min(floor(abs(xg1-xg2)),[],2);
```

or a single line implementation

```
[~,I]=min(floor(abs(meshgrid(xGrid,1:length(x))-ndgrid(x,1:length(xGrid)))),[],2);
```

Example: `xGrid=[1 2 3 4 5], x=[2.5; 1.3; 1.7; 4.8; 3.3]`

Result:

```
I =
     2
     1
     1
     4
     3
```

Comment: Question.  Shouldn't the output `I` be `I = [2 1 1 4 3];`?

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I have corrected the answer: floor() solves the problem

Comment: Thank you, nice solution, also faster than the original one.

Answer (score 2):

See if this works for you -

```
matches  = bsxfun(@le,xGrid(1:end-1),x(:)) & bsxfun(@ge,xGrid(2:end),x(:))
[valid,pos] = max(cumsum(matches,2),[],2)
pos = pos.*(valid~=0)
```

Sample run -

```
xGrid =
     5     2     1     6     8     9     2     1     6
x =
     3     7    14
pos =
     8
     4
     0
```

Explanation on the sample run -

First element of x, `3` occurs last between `...1 6` with the criteria of **`xGrid(i) <= xi <= xGrid(i+1)`** at the backend of `xGrid` and that `1` is at the eight position, so the first element of the output `pos` is `8`. This continues for the second element `7`, which is found between `6 and 8` and that `6` is at the fourth place in `xGrid`, so the second element of the output is `4`. For the third element `14` which doesn't find any neighbours to satisfy the criteria **`xGrid(i) <= xi <= xGrid(i+1)`** and is therefore outputted as `0`.

Comment: This method is a few times faster than my own approach. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for the comparisons and exploiting `find`-like capabilities of [`max`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html)'s second output:

```
xGrid = [2 4 6 8]; %// example data
x = [3 6 5.5 10 -10]; %// example data
comp = bsxfun(@gt, xGrid(:), x(:).'); %'// see if "x" > "xGrid"
[~, result] = max(comp, [], 1); %// index of first "xGrid" that exceeds each "x"
result = result-1; %// subtract 1 to find the last "xGrid" that is <= "x"
```

This approach gives `0` for values of `x` that lie outside `xGrid`. With the above example values,

```
result =
     1     3     2     0     0
```

Comment: About 20 times faster than the original solution. Thanks.